# str_replace for changing URL to wp-content folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to replace the URL to the wp-content folder to point to a different domain, but without changing the setup in Setting or wp-config.

I tried this in functions:

```
// Replace links
$uri = "https://blog.example.com/";
$newuri = str_replace("https://blog.example.com/","https://www.example.com/blog/",$uri);
```

But it's not working...

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your code is working fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f94bea667549c872ddc038cf087bad801b708f45

Comment: Interesting.... It's not working for me... All the links to the resources in the html are still pointing to https://blog.example.com/...

Comment: How you use that `$newuri` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem, maybe because of SSL. The URL starts with `http://...` but you are trying to replace `https://...`